# Multiple potential values for an IIF statement?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to write a report for student grades. One of the subjects has 3 teachers that swap classes a lot. I have a subreport in my report that pulls through target grades from a separate dataset. One of the parameters for the subreport is 'Teacher Initials'. As they swap students frequently, a lot of the time, the students have a new teacher to the one who set them their target grade and so it is not pulled through. Is there a way of having multiple values in an IIF statement for the parameter, such as:

```
IIF(Fields.SubjectName.Value = "Design & Technology"
    , "ABC" OR "DEF" OR "GHI"
    , Fields.TeacherInitials.Value
)
```

Is this possible or am I just doing some wishful thinking and need to find a way to integrate the targets into my initial SQL query?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I "think" you can do this using something like

```
IIF(Fields.SubjectName.Value = "Design & Technology"
    , SPLIT("ABC,DEF,GHI", ",")
    , Fields.TeacherInitials.Value
)
```

Your target parameter (the the sub/drilldown report) would need to be multivalue.

However, this approach seems unmaintainable as you would have to change the expressions if teachers changed.

A better way would be to not pass in the teacher at all (if that's possible) and/or have the teachers looked up in the subreport from a table or better still a view that list teachers and subjects.

If this does not help, post some sample data (as text) and the expected outcome and it will be easier to understand the problems you face.